# Parquet binary UTF8 as string on hive

Tags: hive, parquet, sqldatatypes

There is a parquet file with a `binary (UTF8)` column named `abc` in it.
Is it possible to create an `external` table on hive that will contain the same column `abc`, but casted to `string`?

The structure of the parquet file:

```
$ parquet-tools schema ~/Downloads/dataset.gz.parquet
message spark_schema {
  optional binary abc (UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Try `select cast(abc as string) from mytable` or similar? There's also `decode` function or `base64`. If you explain what is inside binary data that would be more useful.

Comment: @Hitobat I want to remove the burden of casting types from the users. Do you think it might be possible?

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now. In this case, you can have an external-table to read the data, and then define a view based on the table for your users to query from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different types involved:

- There is a SQL schema for the table in Hive. Each column has a type, like STRING or DECIMAL. Each table (or partition in case it's a partitioned table) consist of multiple files  that must be of the same file format, for example PLAINTEXT, AVRO or PARQUET.
- Each of the individual files will have type information as well (except PLAINTEXT). In the case of Parquet, this means two further levels:

  - The [physical type](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L32) describes the storage size, for example INT32, BYTE_ARRAY or FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY.
  - The [logical type](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md) tells applications how to interpret the data, for example UTF8 or DECIMAL.

The STRING column type of Hive is stored as a BYTE_ARRAY physical type (called binary in Parquet schema definitions) with the UTF8 logical type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can simply specify `string` as the type of the column and it will be taken care of.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dataset`(  
    `abc` string)                                
  STORED AS parquet
  LOCATION                                            
    '...';
```